# Is dereferencing a pointer to a pointer to an int the same thing as dereferencing a pointer to a pointer to a char, in the C language?

Tags: c, pointers

Let's say in that situation you are wanting to store an address after you dereference your pointer to pointer. Does it make any difference, functionally and in any other way, to dereference it as:

```
    *(int **)(/* some void ptr */) = // some other address;
```

versus

```
    *(char **)(/* same void ptr */) = // some other address;
```

Because I know when you dereference just a pointer to an int, and just a pointer to a char, they are completely different things! But when dealing with pointers to pointers, there is a layer in between, and since all pointers (on the same machine) are of the same size, I was wondering if there was any difference at all in those two approaches

->edit: Literally could you even replace it with unsigned ptr ptr, long ptr ptr, and void ptr ptr, and get the same thing?

Comment: The only thing you know is that all pointers are convertible to void pointers. Moreover, what you're doing is undefined behaviour unless you can make some guarantees about the "some void ptr".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your assumption that "all pointers (on the same machine) are of the same size" is incorrect.  It may well be true for your particular machine, and it's fairly likely to be true on any machine you're likely to use, but the C standard makes no such guarantee, and there have been real-world machines where it's not true.  For example, on a word-addressed machine, an `int*` might be represented as a word pointer, but a `char*` or `void*` might require additional information to specify which byte within a word it refers to.  And function pointers, on some architectures, are quite different beasts than data pointers.

If you find yourself casting pointer types, it's likely that there's something wrong with your design, and the pointer should have been of the correct type in the first place.

That's not always true, of course; there are case where that kind of low-level access is appropriate and necessary, and one of C's great strengths is that it allows you to do that kind of thing.

But it's difficult to tell whether it's appropriate without a more concrete example.

The point of having distinct types isn't just that they have different sizes or representations; the point is that they're used for different purposes.  An `int*` points to an `int`; a `char*` points to a `char`.

The difference between your examples is that one refers to an `int*` object, and the other refers to a `char*` object.  They're different types, and they're not interchangeable, even if they happen to have the same size and representation.  Your commented-out `some other address` on the right hand side of the assignment has to be some actual expression, and it has to be of some type.

What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 2):

You can cast a pointer to be whatever other type you'd like. In most modern implementations, the pointer type is of the same size as any other pointer type, regardless of what the data is pointing to.

However, C++ is stricter than C when it comes to type correctness, so you'll probably see an "invalid conversion" error if you were to blindly assign the pointer of one type to another one.

Comment: As I said in another comment and in my answer, there is no guarantee in the language that all pointers are the same size.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Can you refer to a section in the C standard? I looked, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: The point is that there's nothing in the standard that says pointers *are* the same size.  In the absence of such a statement, there's no requirement for conforming implementations to make them the same size.  And 6.2.6.1p1 says "The representations of all types are unspeciﬁed except as stated in this subclause.".  For a plausible scenario, see the discussion of word-addressed machines in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yep, all the same size - size of the pointer, funny memory models aside. And yes you will get the same thing.

Comment: How do you know they're the same size?

Comment: This is not guaranteed by the standard---though it is usually the case, and perish the thought of working on a platform where it is not. The standard only guarantees that a `void*` will be able to represent any other pointer type except a pointer-to-function.

Comment: @dmckee: "perish the thought" -- why?  As long as you don't write code that assumes all pointers are the same size (and there should rarely be any need to do so), it shouldn't be a problem.